# Exception gets thrown but isn't caught in c++ program

Tags: c++, exception, cmd, windows-10, try-catch

I am writing a c++ program for an exercise in university and they want us to throw some exceptions and then catch them and print a message. As you can see, i am throwing a Denominator_Is_Zero exception if either one of the given denominators is 0 but if you run the program on your own, you can see that it just crashes when the exception is thrown which means that it doesn't get caught at all. What am i missing here?

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

// function forward declarations
void calculateResults(int, int, int, int);
void checkIfDenomIsZero(int , int);

int main() {
  class Denominator_Is_Zero{};
  class Negative_Sqrt_Argument{};

  cout << "Plese insert four integers: \n"; // prompt the user for input
  int numin1,denom1,numin2,denom2; // fraction related variables declaration
  cin >> numin1 >> denom1 >> numin2 >> denom2;
  try {
    checkIfDenomIsZero(denom1,denom2);
    // Otherwise start calculating the desired fraction related values
    calculateResults(numin1,denom1,numin2,denom2);
  } catch(Denominator_Is_Zero &diz) {
    cout << "caught";
    std::cerr << "The denominator cannot be 0!" << '\n';
  } catch(Negative_Sqrt_Argument &nsa) {
    std::cerr << "The square root's argument cannot be negative!" << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}

// This function checks if either one of the fractions's denominators is 0 and if that's the case, throws an exception
void checkIfDenomIsZero(int denom1,int denom2) {
  class Denominator_Is_Zero{}; // An exception that is thrown when either one of the fractions's denominators is 0
  if(denom1 == 0 || denom2 == 0) {
    throw Denominator_Is_Zero();
  }
}

/**
* This function takes in each fraction's numinator and denominator and
* using the fractions's LCM(Least Common Multiplier) implicitly (ar1 *= par2 and ar2 *= par1), it turns them into homonyms and then
* and then subtracts them. After that, if the subtracted numinator and denominator values
* pass the if() check, it calculates their Square Root and print the desired result to the console.
*/
void calculateResults(int num1,int den1,int num2,int den2) {
  // An exception that is thrown when either the numinator or the denominator of the subtracted fraction is negative (A square root cannot take negative values as arguments)
  class Negative_Sqrt_Argument {};
  num1 *= den2;
  num2 *= den1;
  double resNuminator = num1 - num2;
  double resDenominator = den1*den2;

  // Throw the exception based on the condition described in the exception's comment
  if(resNuminator < 0 || resDenominator < 0) {
    throw Negative_Sqrt_Argument();
  } else { // If the condition is false, then calculate the square root values of the resNuminator and resDenominator
    double sqrtResNum = sqrt(resNuminator);
    double sqrtResDen = sqrt(resDenominator);
    cout << sqrtResNum << "/" << sqrtResDen; // Print the desired result to the console
  }
}
```

Comment: The type `Denominator_Is_Zero` in `checkIfDenomIsZero` is distinct from the type `Denominator_Is_Zero` declared in `main`. Declare your exceptions at the namespace level, not locally.

Comment: i thought about that but if i don't add them there then i get a : "...." is not a type

Comment: You should also catch by `const&`

Comment: @SteliosPapamichael Did you try defining them in a global scope, as opposed to function scope?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thanks, that was it. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring two different `Denominator_Is_Zero`'s. One in `main` and one in `checkIfDenomIsZero`.

The two `Denominator_Is_Zero` classes are not interchangeable because they are each declared in two different scopes.

You need to declare a single `Denominator_Is_Zero` class where it will be visible from both `main` and `checkIfDenomIsZero`. In your program defining a single `Denominator_Is_Zero` class globally should suffice.